# Adding to a List causing null reference

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a class which models the format of the CSV being uploaded (I'm using the FileHelpers library):

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class CSVModel
{
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public string Field1;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public string Field2;
}
```

Then I have a class to display the result of the upload after I've parsed the file row-by-row:

```
public class UploadResult
{
    public List<CSVModel> InvalidField;
    public List<CSVModel> Valid;
}
```

I won't go into detail about how I implement FileHelpers because it all works - a file can be uploaded successfully - it only breaks when I try add an instance of the CSV model to a list like so:

```
public static UploadResult ProcessCSV(CSVModel[] records)
{
    UploadResult uploadResult = new UploadResult();

    for (int i = 1; i < records.Length; i++)
    {
        CSVModel csvModel = records[i];

        // check stuff

        uploadResult.Valid.Add(csvModel); // this is where it breaks
    }

    return uploadResult;
}
```

The exception is giving me nothing more than null reference. What could I be doing incorrectly?

**edit:** When I debug, 'csvModel' is definitely not null when I try add it to the List

Comment: Is `uploadResult.Valid` null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Valid` is `null`, you have to initialize it:

```
public class UploadResult
{
    public List<CSVModel> InvalidField = new List<CSVModel>();
    public List<CSVModel> Valid = new List<CSVModel>();
}
```

or via constructor:

```
public class UploadResult
{
    public UploadResult()
    {
        InvalidField =  new List<CSVModel>();
        Valid =  new List<CSVModel>();
    }
    public List<CSVModel> InvalidField;
    public List<CSVModel> Valid;
}
```

Comment: Can only accept the answer in 12 minutes, but this solved it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing UploadResult but not the List properties. Try something like this:

```
UploadResult uploadResult = new UploadResult {
    InvalidField = new List<CSVModel>(),
    Valid = new List<CSVModel>()
};
```

Comment: If you do this and use UploadResult somewhere else, you'll need to remember to initialize the lists. @Tim's method is probably better.